# How can I disable literal values in Vuetify?

Tags: vuejs2, vuetify.js, disable, select-options

I am having problems when using the "item-disabled" prop on the v-select component from vuetify. I am trying to use this with literal options.

Here is the snippet which reproduces the issue:

In this example I would like to disable the option "Buzz".

```js
Vue.use(Vuetify)

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: () => ({
    items: ['Foo', 'Bar', 'Fizz', 'Buzz'],
    disabledItems: ['Buzz'],
  })
})
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900|Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vuetify/1.5.14/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.10/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vuetify/1.5.14/vuetify.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-container fluid grid-list-xl>
      <v-layout wrap align-center>
        <v-flex xs12 sm6 d-flex>
          <v-select :items="items" :item-disabled="disabledItems" box label="Box style"></v-select>
        </v-flex>
      </v-layout>
    </v-container>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

```
<v-select :items="items" :item-disabled="disabledItems"></v-select>
...
items: ['Foo', 'Bar', 'Fizz', 'Buzz'],
disabledItems: ['Buzz'],
```

I do realize that I could use the non-literal key-value pair like in this example: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/joyoaj and it would work. But I would prefer to not have to write a wrapper component to convert literal options to key-value just to work around this.

```
<v-select :items="items"></v-select>
...
items: [
  {text: 'Foo', value: 'Foo'}, 
  {text: 'Bar', value: 'Bar'}, 
  {text: 'Fizz', value: 'Fizz'}, 
  {text: 'Buzz', value: 'Buzz', disabled: true},
],
```

Does anyone know how to get disabling literal values working?

Comment: Indeed, I tried for an hour, read issues on the vuetify's github, looked into it but nothing worked so far. I'll dig into it a bit more.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You cant do it like that because `item-disabled` property is actually for something else.

From [docs](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/selects#api):

> `item-disabled`
>    Default: `disabled`
>    Type: string | array | function
>
> Set property of items's disabled value

So `item-disabled` just specifies which field on the objects will be treated as "disabled-field". By default, that field is `disabled`.

Without `item-disabled` you would have objects like this:

```
items: [
  {text: 'Foo', value: 'Foo'}, 
  {text: 'Buzz', value: 'Buzz', disabled: true},
],
```

And if objects have some other "disabled-property" (e.g. `customDisabled`) then use `item-disabled` prop like this:

```
 <v-select :items="items" item-disabled="customDisabled"

// ...
items: [
  {text: 'Foo', value: 'Foo'}, 
  {text: 'Buzz', value: 'Buzz', customDisabled: true},
],
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/yWMYMV)

If you need to preserve your arrays of strings then you could just map items to the array of objects and pass it:

```
<v-select :items="computedItems"
// ...
data: () => ({
  items: ['Foo', 'Bar', 'Fizz', 'Buzz'],
  disabledItems: ['Buzz'],
}), 
computed: {
  computedItems() {
    return this.items.map(item => {
      return {
        text: item, 
        disabled: this.disabledItems.includes(item)
      }
    })
  }
}
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BeWoVN)

---

Additionally, you can pass array to reach desired depth if your disabled field is nested, for example:

```
:item-disabled="['meta', 'disabled']"
// ...
{
  text: item, 
  meta: {
    disabled: true 
  }
}
```

Comment: disabled: true did not work for me, here is a workaround i used for this issue for vuetify3 - https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/discussions/16816#discussioncomment-5181081

Answer (score 3):

Real working minimal example with function checking per item.

```
<v-select
  :items="items"
  item-text="name"
  item-value="id"
  :item-disabled="checkIsItemDisabled"
/>

<script>
  data: function(){
    return {
      items: [
        {id: 1, name: 'Foo'},
        {id: 2, name: 'Bar'},
      ],
    },
    methods: {
      checkIsItemDisabled(item) {
        return (item.id === 1)
      },
    }
  },
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding the function option to @Traxo's answer:

```
<v-select :items="items" item-disabled="disableItem">
...
methods: {
  disableItem(item) {
    if (item.prop === this.anyOtherPropValue) {
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  },
},
```

Yes is reactive in case this.anyOtherPropValue change

Comment: So you can skip the if statement by return item.prop === this.anyOtherPropValue

Comment: But I can't get this working I switch to @Traxo answer