# Vuetify v-select + item-disabled how to use it?

Tags: javascript, vuetify.js, show, v-model, v-select

at sample of
https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/selects/#multiple

```
<v-select
          v-model="value"
          :items="items"          
          multiple
          item-disabled=['foo','fizz'] //read only not work?
></v-select>
<script>
  export default {
    data: () => ({
      items: ['foo', 'bar', 'fizz', 'buzz'],
      value: ['foo', 'bar', 'fizz', 'buzz'],
    }),
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in the [Vuetify documentation](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-select/#props), your items can be an array of objects with the following properties:

```js
{
  text: string | number | object,
  value: string | number | object,
  disabled: boolean,
  divider: boolean,
  header: string
}
```

Your example becomes:

```
<template>
  <v-select
    v-model="value"
    :items="items"          
    multiple
  ></v-select>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data: () => ({
    items: [
      {
        text: "foo",
        value: "foo",
        disabled: true,
      },
      {
        text: "bar",
        value: "bar",
      },
      {
        text: "fizz",
        value: "fizz",
        disabled: true,
      },
      {
        text: "buzz",
        value: "buzz",
      },
    ],
  }),
};
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, how about --- item-disabled ---

Comment: Here is direct link to the v-select items format on Vuetify V2 documentation: https://v2.vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-select/#props-items or not-so-great latest (V3) Vuetify documentation: https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-select/#props-items

Comment: disabled: true did not work for me, here is a workaround i used for this issue for vuetify3 - https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/discussions/16816#discussioncomment-5181081

Answer (score 1):

For vuetify versions above 3.0.0 you can use the item slot template, where you can customize the v-list-item

```
<v-select
    :items="items"
    v-model="itemsSelected"
    item-title="title"
    item-value="id"
    multiple
  >
    <template v-slot:item="{ props, item }">
      <v-list-item
        v-bind="props"
        :subtitle="item.raw.department"
        :disabled="item.raw.disabled"
      ></v-list-item>
    </template>
  </v-select>
```

items disabled property can be customized, or you can write your own function

```
const items = [
{
  title: 'Anästhesie',
  id: 442,
  disabled: false,
},
{
  title: 'Anästhesie disabled',
  id: 443,
  disabled: true,
},
```

]

[code sample on vuetify play](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#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)

Comment: I noticed in Vuetify 3, adding "item-props" achieves the same: https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#eNp9UUFugzAQ/MrKFxIpIVGSE0oqReql5x4TDhQW1ZIBy164IH7Tn/RjXRuchLTqyXhmdrwzXHphTb45ax13LYpEHAkrrTLCl2sNcOzWmdb+01/ypqZM1mgmyIMWFeYUAIBEsoc9XYU/r+LOdOuqKVAF6t0PYvEoccSaJClklT9/sV2mWsfK2WDVKpKa5XOxNo22AbtvvQlrh2wMzMM5ZMx+3Dx0wlebG6kJLFI7ViMr3RiCHgyWMEBpmgoirjNycgD2teS3sXCCy/hgH1bxGROIzvX3l6VPtBKjVSBlkcDhsLvdC2mzD4WMlpmyOOHDdP7neRt9Nt//YU6mnXunTznCn+M8nHlx4R3T5Zi2bOucZFODtG8sfZ1MF25uGVY03J1hCWNxeNYxg2t77JebFcNK7ONDvNsK97GNtyL9AaUr1Xc=

Answer (score 0):

As per the github issue raised here [Which is still open]: https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/5557

> If an array is passed it's used as a path to a property (['a', 'b'] is
> 'a.b'), not a list of item values.

So as per now, we cannot pass array directly to item-disabled to make some options disabled.
As mentioned in above answer,
Your current array needs to be converted to array of objects in order for
item-disabled to work. We need to pass array of objects with disabled:true for the objects that needs to be disabled.

```
  [
      {text: 'Bar', value: 'Bar'}, 
      {text: 'Gizz - Disabled', value: 'Gizz', disabled: true}
  ]
```

Here is the example - https://codepen.io/akshayd21/pen/qBqGONz

Similar questions for reference:
[How can I disable literal values in Vuetify?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56151522/how-can-i-disable-literal-values-in-vuetify)
[v-select deactivate some items/options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62592947/v-select-deactivate-some-items-options)